# HTML table, are headers Attribute columns identifiers?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to give to each of my table `<th>`'s an identifier, so It won't matter the other when I am using the `<td>` (while I know the identifier), I found this ([HTML  headers Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_headers.asp)), which seems like what I need:

```html
     <table>
      <tr>
        <th id="name">Name</th>
        <th id="email">Email</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td headers="name">John Doe</td>
        <td headers="email">someone@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

But I change the order of the `<td>`'s like this, first the email and then the name:

```html
     <table>
      <tr>
        <th id="name">Name</th>
        <th id="email">Email</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td headers="email">someone@example.com</td>
        <td headers="name">John Doe</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

And as you can see the result that I get is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The **[header attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43.html)** has no effect on presentation; it will not swap table cells around. The header attribute simply denotes which `<th>` cells the `<td>` cells relate to for the purposes of enhancing screen readers:

> This allows screen readers to speak the headers associated with each data cell when the relationships are too complex to be identified using the *`<th>`* element alone or the *`<th>`* element with the *`scope`* attribute.

Note that each `<td>` cell can relate to **more than one** header cell, if the table contains more than one header row. For example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" id="h">Homework</th>
    <th colspan="3" id="e">Exams</th>
    <th colspan="3" id="p">Projects</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="e1" headers="e">1</th>
    <th id="e2" headers="e">2</th>
    <th id="ef" headers="e">Final</th>
    <th id="p1" headers="p">1</th>
    <th id="p2" headers="p">2</th>
    <th id="pf" headers="p">Final</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="h">15%</td>
    <td headers="e e1">15%</td>
    <td headers="e e2">15%</td>
    <td headers="e ef">20%</td>
    <td headers="p p1">10%</td>
    <td headers="p p2">10%</td>
    <td headers="p pf">15%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In order to swap table cells around, you'd be much better off using either **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** (making use of **[`flex-direction`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)**) or a JavaScript solution.